# Can I access bound data without D3?

Tags: d3.js

My understanding is that D3 binds data to the DOM. Is is possible to retrieve this data using just Javascript (without D3)?

I tried

```
d3.select('p').data([5]);
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].attributes.item(0)
```

but nothing turned up.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - it's not an attribute, it's a property of the node itself:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].__data__    //5
```

Comment: This is also useful to know when debugging -- you can see the bound data in the "properties" tab of your DOM inspector!